# UnicodeDecodeError when add new list to excel using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I try to add new sheet to excel file with

```
def add_xlsx_sheet(df, sheet_name=u'Десктопы кратко', index=True, digits=2, path=None):
book = load_workbook(path)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
if sheet_name in list(writer.sheets.keys()):
    sh = book.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
    book.remove_sheet(sh)
df.to_excel(excel_writer=writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, startrow=0, startcol=0,
            float_format='%.{}f'.format(digits), index=index)
pd.DataFrame({}).to_excel(writer, sheet_name=u'Смартфоны кратко')
pd.DataFrame({}).to_excel(writer, sheet_name=u'Смартфоны полно')
writer.save()

df.groupby('member_id').apply(lambda x: add_xlsx_sheet(x, u'Десктопы полно', path='{}.xlsx'.format(x.name)))
```

and get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/�����/PycharmProjects/14-27/desktop.py", line 142, in <module>
df.groupby('member_id').apply(lambda x: add_xlsx_sheet(x, u'Десктопы полно'.decode('utf-8'), path='{}.xlsx'.format(x.name)))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

I asked this question earlier, but it didn't solve. I try check it with `'Десктопы полно'.decode('utf-8')` but it doesn't help.

Comment: The error message source line doesn't match the code you've presented.

Comment: If possible, I would suggest you look at using openpyxl 2.4 (currently in beta) which provides some tools for working with Pandas. See http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pandas.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
df.groupby('member_id').apply(lambda x: add_xlsx_sheet(x, u'Десктопы полно', path='u{}.xlsx'.format(x.name)))
```

If this doesn't work you may need to decode `x.name`. Or switch to Python 3.

Comment: Then `…format(x.name.decode(relevant encoding))`as I suggested.

Comment: unfortinately, it doesn't work. Maybe I need in other encoding

Comment: Only you know which encoding you have. Easy enough to try out if you break these out into smaller steps.